# Create dynamic URL to open specific record for editing (PHP/POST)

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have a search page using POST to search MySQL.  The results page returns all records meeting the criteria.  I have a separate modify page (requiring a password) that returns the specific record to be edited.  Users then make the edits and commit the changes.

Currently each record on the results page has a link to the modify page.  The user then has to re-enter the record to modify.

What I'd like to do is have a dynamic link on each record returned by the search page so that the user is brought to the modify page specifically for the chosen record (skipping the need to re-enter the desired record).

I've searched for answers and haven't found anything.  Maybe I'm just not using the correct terminology to search for.  I'm hoping someone can enlighten me as to how accomplish this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

generate the result links like this

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo <<<HERE
<p>{$row['blahbla']}</p>
<a href="modify.php?id={$row['id']}>Edit</a>"
HERE;
}
```

And load your modify page with that id.

Comment: The URLs are created fine but the modify page doesn't return any records.  Specifically, the empty results message displays.  No matching records for xxxx.  Curiously the xxxx is blank so I don't think the id is getting to the query string.

Comment: What piece of code would be best?  Just my implementation of your sample?

Comment: Yes. Just post your code so i can see if any problem!